# os.chdir and russian path name

Tags: python, string, localization

Trying to run this code

```
path= "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Новая папка\Новая папка"

os.chdir(path)
```

which give me error:

```
line 9, in <module>    os.chdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\
xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\\\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\x
b2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
```

How can I fix it, or it supports only english?

Comment: try escaping the backslashes or making it a raw string - `r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\Новая папка\Новая папка"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use raw string:

```
path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\Новая папка\Новая папка"
os.chdir(path)
```